# Connecting to gremlin server from python API duplicates log messages

Tags: python-3.x, logging, gremlin, tinkerpop3

After connecting to a Gremlin Server, all of my log messages are duplicated. I am using the following code to connect.

```py
graph = anonymous_traversal.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection("ws://localhost:8182/gremlin", "g"))
```

I guess that the gremlin-python API somehow enable the root logger, but I can not find it where. Maybe I overlooked some settings. Any bits of advice to overcome this issue is very welcome.

Here is the whole sample code which I used to replicate this problem.

```py
import logging

from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection
from gremlin_python.process import anonymous_traversal
```

I used to test this as the main entry point of the script.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Setting up my local logger instance

```py
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.getLevelName('DEBUG'))

    log_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    log_file_handler = logging.FileHandler('foo.log', mode='w')
    log_file_handler.setFormatter(log_format)
    log_file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(log_file_handler)

    console_log_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_log_handler.setLevel(logging.getLevelName('INFO'))
    console_log_handler.setFormatter(log_format)
    logger.addHandler(console_log_handler)
```

And sending some messages to log before the connection estabilished.

```py
    logger.debug("foo")
    logger.info("foo")
    logger.warning("and")
    logger.error("foo again")
```

Comment/uncomment the following line to test without gremlin connection

```py
    graph = anonymous_traversal.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection("ws://localhost:8182/gremlin", "g"))
```

Finally, sending some more message afte the connection.

```py
    logger.debug("after foo")
    logger.info("after foo")
    logger.warning("after and")
    logger.error("after foo again")
```

The result is something like this.

```
2019-04-18 16:09:57,746 - INFO - foo
2019-04-18 16:09:57,746 - WARNING - and
2019-04-18 16:09:57,746 - ERROR - foo again
DEBUG:__main__:after foo
2019-04-18 16:09:59,107 - INFO - after foo
INFO:__main__:after foo
2019-04-18 16:09:59,107 - WARNING - after and
WARNING:__main__:after and
2019-04-18 16:09:59,108 - ERROR - after foo again
ERROR:__main__:after foo again
```

I think gremlin should use its own logger and should not cause any side effects in the working of other logger instances.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple workaround. It is not pretty.

```py
def non_root_logger():
    for handler in logging.root.handlers:
        logging.root.removeHandler(handler)
    return logging.getLogger(__name__)
```